# A round of introductions: A graph problem?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-designs

There is an introductory session for $n$ people. And to allow some conversation, we split the group into $k$ groups of similar sizes $s$. This is repeated until each person shared a group with everybody else. However, it can be boring to talk to someone twice.

How to split the groups such that each person shares a group with every other participant exactly once while maintaining a group size of roughly $s$?

I'm most interested in $s = 3,4,5$ as they are socially most beneficial. I'm also interested in a computational ways to solve for $10 < n < 100$.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but if $n=15$ and $s=3$ this is [Kirkman's schoolgirl problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem).

Comment: @bof: Thanks, the wiki also suggests that the general problem is called 'orthogonal regrouping'.